# View added to Layout inherits parent's style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-styles

I'm reusing a custom `InputDialog` that `extends DialogFragment` and adding a <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on the `EditInputDialog` All this works fine, but now I'm playing around with styles and found this quirky little problem:

[image: delete button]

I'd like for the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button to use the default device style for buttons

Here is the simple style for the layout (/res/values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="myBackgroundStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Here is how I'm creating and adding the button:

```
Button btnDelete = new Button(getActivity());
btnDelete.setText("Delete");
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.btnSave);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, R.id.btnSave);
btnDelete.setLayoutParams(lp);
rl.addView(btnDelete);
```

I've also tried applying style to the button upon creation, such as:

```
new Button(getActivity(),null,android.R.attr.buttonStyle);
```

`.buttonStyle` isn't the only one I've tried

But it doesn't help at all. Is there something I'm missing, or what is going on with this?

That style is not what I'm eventually going to go with, this was simply for testing and then I ran into this issue.

Comment: Try passing the dialog's context (`getDialog().getContext`) instead of the activity context to the button constructor, as that should provide the correct theme.

Comment: wow, so simple. it works! Add as answer and I'll accept. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the dialog's context instead of the activity context to the button so that it can retrieve the correct theme (the `Dialog` base class uses a `ContextThemeWrapper` to wrap the activity context while providing it's own theme).

Replacing the `getActivity()` that was passed to the button constructor with `getDialog().getContext()` should fix the issue. Note that the `LayoutInflater` that is passed to the `onCreateView()` callback is initialized with the correct context, and you can also retrieve it from there by calling `inflater.getContext()`.